# TransportClientEndpointBehavior in .net core

Tags: .net, .net-core, azureservicebus, servicebus

I'm migrating an application running on `.NET Framework 4.6` to `.NET Core 3.1`.

The problem is that the application uses the `WCF ServiceBus` which is not fully integrated into `.NET Core`.

```
var uri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("scheme", "namespace", "path");

var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(uri);

var channel = new ChannelFactory<ICustomChannel>(new NetTcpBinding(), endpointAddress);

var tokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(token, accessKey);

channelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new TransportClientEndpointBehavior
{
    TokenProvider = tokenProvider
});
```

`ServiceBusEnvironment` and `TransportClientEndpointBehavior` are not avilable in `.NET Core`. Is there any possible way or practice to replace it and make it work on `.NET Core`?

Answer (score 0):

,NET core hasn't going to get more features since 2019 and it will also lose support in dec of 2022.

So I would suggest upgrading to the latest versions such as .net5 or .net6.

Please refer the following [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/supporting-the-community-with-wf-and-wcf-oss-projects/) for alternatives.

Please alse refer the following [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/)  for Wcf core.